# C# - How to save images from a dictionary<string, images> to a folder

Tags: c#, dictionary, game-engine

I am currently working on a 2D Game Engine, so far I have added a feature to load and remove images, but now I want to save them, this is the dictionary:

`public Dictionary<string, Image> images = new Dictionary<string, Image>();`

The string is the name, for example when the person wants to add an image they click a button that says choose image then a pitcurebox will be set as the image that was opened, then there is a textbox, when they click a button that says Add Image, it will do this images.Add(textBox1.Text, pictureBox1.Image) Then I want to save all the images added to a folder

I have looked all over the internet for this, but no one has an answer for me, and I'm really stuck, thanks in advance.

Comment: In what format do you want to save it ? Save all images as files in a folder ?

Comment: Only images? as Jpeg, png etc.? or the whole information string+image and how u are going use the saved images/data again? Please elaborate to get specific answer.

Comment: The String is the name, for example when the person wants to add an image they click a button that says choose image then a pitcurebox will be set as the image that was opened, then there is a textbox, when they click a button that says Add Image, it will do this


`images.Add(textBox1.Text, pictureBox1.Image)`
Then I want to save all the images added to a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Image` class has the `Save` method. So you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var imgX in images.Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
{
    imgX.Save("figure_a_file_path_and_name", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

## UPDATE

If you would like to use the string in the dictionary as file name change the above code a little bit:

```
var folder = "figure_the_folder_path\\";

foreach (var entry in images)
{
    var destinationFile = string.Concat(folder, entry.Key); 
    var img = entry.Value;
    img.Save(destinationFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save image to single folder with BinaryFormatter to serialize/deserialize your dictionary to file like this:

```
public void Save(string filename)
{
    var bin_formater = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = File.Create(filename))
    {
        bin_formater.Serialize(stream, images); //images is your dictionary
    }
}
```